# How to remove unnecessary whitespaces from string, so there are no extra spaces in HTML

Tags: php, html

How to remove unnecessary whitespaces from string, so there are no extra spaces in HTML??

Im getting string from DB and for now I'm trying to do something like:

```
nl2br(trim(preg_replace('/(\r?\n){3,}/', '$1$1', $comment->text)));
```

But it keep displaying like that:

[image]

What I need is to get perfect:

[image]

How it is done?? Because I'm bad at regex :(

**EDIT:**
$comment->text contains text from DB:

[image]

Comment: What does `$comment->text` contain? Can you post the output of `var_dump($comment->text);`?

Comment: Amal Murali, I've edited question

Comment: Please show the output of `var_dump($comment->text)` from the browser's page source, not as rendered in the browser or DB client, so we can see the string lengths and all the whitespace intact.

Comment: Can you show your HTML source? I'm confused, browsers already automatically collapse whitespace for you when it renders the data. Not sure why all of this is necessary unless you are talking about vertical space which is controlled by the box model.

Comment: As I marked in image, yes I want to get rid of vertical space

Comment: Yes, please look at the page source, not what is rendered by the DOM inspector as you have in your image.  The DOM inspector does all sorts of things to reorganize whitespace because its purpose is viewing the DOM tree, not the source.  Ctl-U or Option-U to view source in most browsers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/(\r)|(\n)/', '', $comment->text);
```

Output

```
"1 2"<br>"2 3"<br>"3"<br>"4"<br>"5"
```

Comment: preg_replace('/(\r)|(\n)/', '<br>', $comment->text); That's what I wanted :)

Comment: ah sorry, I misunderstood the question :)

Comment: @AigarsCibuļskis Note that this will produce `<br>` tags one after another if your line endings are like `\r\n` or if you have more than one `\n` or `\r` in your input string.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this str_replace if you want to remove just spaces

```
$string = str_replace(' ', '', $string);
```

or if you want to remove all whitespeces use this

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine and also avoids multiple `<br>` tags following each other:

```
$string = '12
23
3
4
5
6';

var_dump(implode("\n<br>\n", preg_split('/(\r?\n)+/', $string)));

var_dump(preg_replace('/(\r?\n)+/', "\n<br>\n", $string));
```

**Output:**

```
string(38) "12
<br>
23
<br>
3
<br>
4
<br>
5
<br>
6"

string(38) "12
<br>
23
<br>
3
<br>
4
<br>
5
<br>
6"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use simple CSS

```css
p.a {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<p class="a">
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
</p>
```